# how to retrieve results for past n days using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgres

**What I'm trying to do:**
Get results across previous `n` days everytime I run the query on a given day without manually updating the start and end dates.

**example query:**
If I were running the query today (June 23rd,2019)
My query to retrieve results for the past 8 days would look like

```
select count(*),state,DATE(date)
from animal_shelter
where date=>'2019-06-15' and date <='2019-06-22'
group by state,DATE(date);
```

but this requires manual intervention where I'm updating two dates every single time.

I found that there's

```
now()::date - interval '8 days'
```

which can be used but I didn't understand how to modify use it with the between condition.

*Possible solution*

```
select count(*),state,DATE(date)
from animal_shelter
where date=> ( now()::date - interval '8 days') 
group by state,DATE(date);
```

Is this right, and can I be assured that it picks exactly the 8 past days worth of data not including today?

Please help me accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for:

```
WHERE date between now()::date - interval '8 days' AND now()::date - interval '1 day';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also make use of the `current_date` function mentioned here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

so the answer would be like

```
where date = current_date - interval 'n day'
```